# What's the point of this makefile architecture?

Tags: makefile

I have a program I'm trying to compile, lets call it P. P needs a 3rd party library, L1. L1 needs another library, L2. So far, nothing is that weird.

The Makefile for P basically just sets some variables, and then includes the makefile for L1.

The makefile for L1 does a whole bunch of variable setting and stuff, (including a list of files to compile, for example) and then includes L2's makefile.

L2s makefile does a whole LOT of work and actually makes all 3.

My problem is that L2 doesn't want to compile.

However, I already HAVE a binary version of both libraries for my system, but I can't use them because the L2 makefile does all of the work.

Also, if you compile with dynamic libraries, it's going to look for the libraries to load in your compile directory, at runtime, which isn't where they belong on the production system.

My question is: Why the heck did they design it this way?

Comment: Is the stuff it is compiling a compiler? some bootstrapping process maybe?

Comment: @JDehaan: As I commented below, nope, it's all communications libraries.

Comment: Perhaps if you provided more detail people would provide better answers, just a thought.  I don't know why you wouldn't just link against a built library and compile that separately.

Comment: @Will, I'm not sure what added detail would be helpful. P is a program that simulates a modem for faxing, L1 is a SIP/H323 communications library, and L2 is (I think) I more generic (telephone?) communications library. (P is t38modem, L1 is OPAL, L2 is ptlib, if that helps any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because they maintain both libraries and the program - and for them, the compilations work and by doing it this way, they are guaranteed that both libraries are fully up to date (and hence that the program has the latest code to use).

Comment: Not really. L1 and L2 Might have originally been by the same people, but P is a totally different product. But it makes it very difficult to actually USE ...

Fundamentally, you are probably correct, but it's very annoying.

Comment: Yes - if you can't build the libraries accurately, it is hard to use them.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like something that grew organically:

1. Someone wrote L2's Makefile and made it very complex and powerful. This Makefile uses variables, such as lists of objects, and builds them up from whatever they start with (like, say, nothing).

   Someone (else?) had to write L1's Makefile and decided to piggyback by constructing L1's lists and then handing everything over to L2's Makefile, rather than try to reinvent all that machinery.

   Someone at your shop had to write P's Makefile and piggybacked on L1's Makefile.

The trouble with this design (apart from its being hard to untangle) is that it's only as good as the worst Makefile in the chain (probably made by someone else). If L2 isn't compiling, then either some Makefile has included a delicate Makefile and broken it, or else something in the environment has changed that one of the earlier writers counted on. If the L2 Makefile handles dependencies correctly, then you should be able to persuade it to use the libraries without rebuilding them (and you can try making L2 alone to diagnose the problem). If it doesn't, then you'll just have to go spelunking.

Answer (score 0):

I would say for me smells like a bootstrapping process...

Comment: Nope, it's not compiling a compiler or an OS or anything. It's all communication libraries.

Comment: That depends on your definition of 'bootstrapping'.  If it means 'building from the ground up', it doesn't matter that it is communications libraries and programs; the point is that you bootstrap the resulting program by building the component libraries and then the program.  Often, bootstrapping is used for a compiler building itself (witness the GCC build process) or for an O/S getting started - but they're not the only meanings for the term.